# PUT Request fails on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, put, retrofit

Following the REST API,  I encounter an error while using the PUT method through retrofit call. The error occurs only in Lollipop version of android whereas it works fine on the other O.S. as tested thoroughly . I am sending data in the body of the request and while debugging it , it shows that the body has been successfully sent but the server does not receive it .  The error occurs randomly as it may or may not work . What could be the possible reason and solution?

Comment: Many things can go wrong. Can you reproduce the problem and post a stack trace? Or the code snippet where you make a request to the server?